# How to reach last element in forEach() JS

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have tried lots of solutions here but non worked for me. I'm looping node elements, and I want to get to the last one so I update it.

```
app.js

var userLen = document.querySelectorAll('.username').length
document.querySelectorAll('.username').forEach(function (event) {
  event[event === (userLen - 1)].innerHTML =   window.localStorage.getItem('micky')
})
```

I get this error every time Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined.

Comment: What do you expect `event[event === (userLen - 1)]` to be? `event === (userLen - 1)` is either `true` or `false` (it’s actually always `false`, since `event` will always be an `HTMLElement` and `userLen - 1` will always be a number; what are you comparing there?), so you’re accessing `event[true]` or `event[false]`, both of which will be `undefined`. This makes no sense. Even less so, because you’re trying to access some index from a single `HTMLElement`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to loop over element to reach the last one.

Moreover, you are trying to get  `event[true]` or `event[false]` as `event === (userLen - 1)` will return a boolean, not an actual index.

Try this:

```
var nodeElememnts = document.querySelectorAll('.username');
if(nodeElements.length > 0){
    nodeElements[nodeElements.length - 1].innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem('micky');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this w/o using `forEach` here like:

```js
var elm = document.querySelectorAll('.username');
var lastElem = [].slice.call(elm).pop();
if (lastElem) lastElem.innerHTML = 'It Works!';

// For debugging purpose
console.log( [].slice.call(elm) ) //<-- Convert NodeList to Array
console.log( lastElem )
```

```html
<div class="username">A</div>
<div class="username">B</div>
<div class="username">C</div>
```